# Logitech non-unifying receivers compatibility (and ways to get a spare)

Tags: peripherals

I have bought an MK235 keyboard-mouse set and a M220 mouse which I use for different computers. Recently I lost the receiver of the MK235 set, but, doing some testing and the Logitech app, I have found that the M220 receiver is also compatible.

Both of these receivers are P/N C-U0010. After searching a bit in ebay, it seems that this specific P/N is used for variety of products, while it seems that some mouses and keyboards are also compatible with other non-unifying receivers. I have an older one (C-U0003) but it is not compatible, but this does not seem to be the rule. As expected, I have found nothing from official sources. The questions are:

1. Is there any compatibility list for devices and receivers?
2. The standard cost of such a receiver in ebay is 10+ euros. I can get a mouse with the same receiver for a similar price. Is there an official Logitech e-shop to get one at a normal price?
3. Has anyone the wireless mouse B170 or M170 to tell me the P/N of the receiver that comes with the product?

Thanks

Comment: "Is there an official Logitech e-shop" - No;  Why don't you call Logitech and see if they can send you a part and/or provide the P/N to you?

Comment: For your first question, it depends on the mouse and receiver. I have two Logi Tech devices here with different receivers not interchangeable.

Comment: @Ramhound, I live in Greece and there is no such thing as direct Logitech support. There are only resellers who, in Greece, are nothing more than box movers. The Logitech office that supports Greece is in Switzerland.

Comment: @John, there is an utility ("Re-connect Software") from Logitech which allows you to re-pair devices. I have seen posts where people had success re-pairing devices with different receivers. The problem is that there is no such thing as master compatibility list.